# Can't get kwargs data in function in Django Celery Beat

Tags: python, django, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I'm implementing a reminder module in the application using Django [celery-beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), I'm creating [cron tab](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.schedules.html#celery.schedules.crontab) in periodic tasks and passing dictionary in **kwargs** parameter. It's successfully saved in Django periodic task table but when the scheduled task runs on time and calls the mentioned function, it's not getting **kwargs** data and through the exception.

***settings.py***

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [    
    'django_celery_beat',
]

# CELERY STUFF
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://localhost:6379"

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

***init.py***

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

all = ("celery_app",)
```

***celery.py***

```
import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings_local")

app = Celery("baseapp")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

***Here is the task scheduler function which is creating periodic tasks:***

```
def task_scheduler(raw_data):
try:
    if raw_data["start"] and raw_data["reminder"]:
        reminder_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(raw_data["start"], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') - datetime.timedelta(minutes=raw_data["reminder"])
        reminder, _ = CrontabSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
            minute=reminder_time.minute,
            hour=reminder_time.hour,
            day_of_week="*",
            day_of_month=reminder_time.day,
            month_of_year=reminder_time.month,
        )
        PeriodicTask.objects.update_or_create(
            name=raw_data["summary"],
            task="reminder_notification",
            crontab=reminder,
            expire_seconds=7200,             
            kwargs=json.dumps({'test132':'123'}),                

        )
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

***Here is a reminder notification function which is called when the task runs on time:***

```
@shared_task(name="reminder_notification")
def reminder_notification(*args, **kwargs):
    print("hello task")
```

***Here are tasks in the database:***
[image]

***Here is the error:***

```
[2021-01-07 06:13:00,021: ERROR/Beat] Message Error: Couldn't apply scheduled task celery15: reminder_notification() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test132'
['  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>\n    sys.exit(main())\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 15, in main\n    sys.exit(_main())\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 213, in main\n    return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__\n    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main\n    rv = self.invoke(ctx)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke\n    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke\n    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke\n    return callback(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func\n    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 132, in caller\n    return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 327, in worker\n    worker.start()\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start\n    self.blueprint.start(self)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start\n    step.start(parent)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 365, in start\n    return self.obj.start()\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 124, in start\n    self._popen = self._Popen(self)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/context.py", line 276, in _Popen\n    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/context.py", line 333, in _Popen\n    return Popen(process_obj)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/popen_fork.py", line 24, in __init__\n    self._launch(process_obj)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/popen_fork.py", line 79, in _launch\n    code = process_obj._bootstrap()\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 327, in _bootstrap\n    self.run()\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 703, in run\n    self.service.start(embedded_process=True)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 627, in start\n    interval = self.scheduler.tick()\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 339, in tick\n    self.apply_entry(entry, producer=self.producer)\n', '  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 272, in apply_entry\n    exc, traceback.format_stack(), exc_info=True)\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 386, in apply_async
    return task.apply_async(entry_args, entry_kwargs,
  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 526, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
TypeError: reminder_notification() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test132'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 269, in apply_entry
    result = self.apply_async(entry, producer=producer, advance=False)
  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 394, in apply_async
    reraise(SchedulingError, SchedulingError(
  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/exceptions.py", line 104, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 386, in apply_async
    return task.apply_async(entry_args, entry_kwargs,
  File "/home/usman/Documents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 526, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
celery.beat.SchedulingError: Couldn't apply scheduled task celery15: reminder_notification() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test132'
```

****What am I doing wrong?****

Comment: Your error indicates that you have (or had) a *keyword argument* named `test111`  in `reminder_notification()`, Bit, I couldn't see anything like that in the given code

Comment: Also, add your error traceback as "text", not as images

Comment: @JPG during testing, I have tried with different names so it is showing with `test111`. and traceback is added in text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting **kwargs** data successfully.

**Solution:**

The current running worker does not get the updated changes from the function, So we need to stop the worker and run again.

```
celery -A baseapp worker --beat --scheduler django --loglevel=info
```